# Very confused about how to Group by in LINQ, and even more confused about HAVING

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm new to Linq. I'm trying to convert this simple SQL query, but can't find any great resources on how to convert SQL to LINQ. My SQL query is:

```
SELECT SomeValue
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY SomeValue
HAVING SUM (OtherValue) > 0;
```

I don't quite understand LINQ well enough to do this. I'm having a lot of trouble getting GROUP BY to work, I haven't even attempted to tackle HAVING SUM yet.

I've tried a few things. This is the most recent, though it's still very wrong:

```
from entry in SomeTable
group entry by entry.SomeValue into grp
select grp.Select(x => x.SomeValue).toList();
```

Any help or resources would be great.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) ?

Comment: a resource http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the grouping working it looks like you want this (in query syntax instead of lambdas):

```
from entry in SomeTable
group entry by entry.SomeValue into grp
where grp.Sum(x => x.OtherValue) > 0
select grp.Key;
```

Answer (score 4):

An equivalent LINQ statement would look like this:

```
SomeTable.GroupBy(x => x.SomeValue)
         .Where(g => g.Sum(x => x.OtherValue) > 0)
         .Select(g => g.Key);
```

It first groups by `SomeValue`. The result will be a list of groups. Each group in turn contains all rows that have the same `SomeValue`.
The next step creates a filter (`Where`). This filter will return only those group where the sum of `OtherValue` of the rows in this group is greater than zero.
Finally, from the filtered groups it will select the key of each group. The key of a group is the value that has been specified in the `GroupBy`.

Comment: Much better than the LINQ keywords